# How to separate JSON Array with space in PHP

Tags: php, json

I have a JSONArray as

```
{"test":
[
{"Name":"aaa","Reg/Admission Number":"001"},
{...}]}
```

And I can separate Name by

```
$read_data = array();
foreach ($data->test as $result){
  $name = $result->Name;
  $read_data[] = "('$name')";
}
```

the result of **read_data** as **('aaa'),('bbb')...**

Anyone can suggest how to separate the array of `Reg/Admission Number` which has the special character as **'/'** and **'space'**

Comment: inside the for each add this `var_dump($result);` and look the name of that field.

Comment: have you tried using an escape character? like `Reg\/Admission\ Number`? alternatively i believe `$result->{'Reg/Admission Number'}` should work

Comment: @haxxxton $result->{'Reg/Admission Number'}` it works fine.. thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per **@haxxxton** suggestion it works

```
 $read_data = array();
    foreach ($data->test as $result){
      $name = $result->Name;
      $no = $result->{'Reg/Admission Number'}`
      $read_data[] = "('$name','$no')";
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Why Dont you use the php function

1. json_encode() http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php
2. json_decode() http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 0):

You can convert json array to PHP array first and then can do your operation.