# How To Loop Json Array In PHP

Tags: javascript, php, json

**Does anyone know how I can loop this JSON array in PHP? I just tried, but it didn't work**

```
[{
   //
    "data": [{
            "id": "1",
            "name": "Tiger Nixon",
            "position": "System Architect",
            "salary": "$320,800",
            "start_date": "2011/04/25",
            "office": "Edinburgh",
            "extn": "5421"
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "name": "Garrett Winters",
            "position": "Accountant",
            "salary": "$170,750",
            "start_date": "2011/07/25",
            "office": "Tokyo",
            "extn": "8422"
        },
        {
            "id": "3",
            "name": "Ashton Cox",
            "position": "Junior Technical Author",
            "salary": "$86,000",
            "start_date": "2009/01/12",
            "office": "San Francisco",
            "extn": "1562"
        },
        {
            "id": "4",
            "name": "Cedric Kelly",
            "position": "Senior Javascript Developer",
            "salary": "$433,060",
            "start_date": "2012/03/29",
            "office": "Edinburgh",
            "extn": "6224"
        }
    ]
}]
```

Comment: That's just a JSON array. How have you tried to add a loop? Here we expect you to [**try to solve your own problem first**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please attempt something, then update your question to show a **specific** problem you're having in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: You can loop it using `foreach` statement

Comment: in `php` you have to `decode` the json data

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to separate JSON Array with space in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27915040/how-to-separate-json-array-with-space-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

You should convert json to array then for each json convert object to array

```
$json = "current Json data";
$json = json_decode($json); //convert json to array
$json = $json[0]->data; //get all data

foreach ($json as $key => $value) {
    $value = get_object_vars($value); // convert object to array
    print_r($value)
}
```

Comment: It's right I checked it and working, can you try to as per my script?

Answer (score 0):

First, decode your JSON into a PHP array, then you can loop through it as normal.

```
$arrayItems = json_decode($jsonString)

foreach ($arrayItems as $item){
 // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code to iterate json format:

```
$jsonData = json_decode($data);
        foreach($jsonData as $jsonDataKey => $jsonDataValue){
            foreach($jsonDataValue as $jsonArrayKey => $jsonArrayValue){
                echo $jsonArrayValue['id'];
                echo $jsonArrayValue['name'];
                echo $jsonArrayValue['position'];
            }
        }
```